# Detect touch when click on CAShapeLayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I made a blue ball that can be dragged in a red circled path:
[image]

The function of the dragging is working great, BUT! It works wherever I click on the screen, and I want to make it drag **only** when I click on the blue ball.

This is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: earthX,y: earthY), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer2.path = circlePath2.CGPath
        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 7
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
        
        let dragBall = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.dragBall(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(dragBall)
}
@IBAction func dragBall(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.view)
            let earthX = Double(point.x)
            let earthY = Double(point.y)
            let midViewXDouble = Double(midViewX)
            let midViewYDouble = Double(midViewY)
            let angleX = (earthX - midViewXDouble)
            let angleY = (earthY - midViewYDouble)
            angle = atan2(angleY, angleX)
            let earthX2 = midViewXDouble + cos(angle)*100
            let earthY2 = midViewYDouble + sin(angle)*100
            circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: earthX2,y: earthY2), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
            shapeLayer2.path = circlePath2.CGPath
}
```

I tried to add the code below to the dragBall function as if statment: **(It detects if the user touches exactly on the blue ball)**

```
if ((point.x >= circlePath2.currentPoint.x - circlePath2.bounds.width/2) && (point.y <= circlePath2.currentPoint.y + circlePath2.bounds.height/2)) && ((point.y >= circlePath2.currentPoint.y - circlePath2.bounds.height/2) && (point.y <= circlePath2.currentPoint.y + circlePath2.bounds.height/2)){
```

And it worked, but I can drag it only when my touch do not leave the blue ball position, for example if I want to start touching the ball only when I touch him - I can, but keep moving him when my dragging is somewhere else in the screen - I can't.

**Shortcut: Start dragging the ball only when I touch it & keep dragging when my touching is anywhere the screen.**

Answer (score 2):

In your `dragBall` function, read your gesture recognizer's `state` property. If the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and the touch is inside the blue ball, then the gesture has started correctly and you can allow the subsequent gestures to affect the position of the ball even if they are not inside the ball.

The best approach would probably be to assign a `delegate` to the gesture recognize when you create it that conforms to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, then implement the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` function. In this function, if the touch is not inside the blue ball, return false.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about with the delegate:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  let ballView = UIView()

  func createRecognizer() {
      let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.gestureRecognized(_:)))
      recognizer.delegate = self
      ballView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
  }

  func gestureRecognized(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
      // update ball position
  }

  func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      let location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(ballView)
      return CGRectContainsPoint(ballView.bounds, location)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? when I change the UIPanGestureRecognizer to UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan is gives me an error

Comment: But the ball is not a UIView, its CAShapeLayer

Comment: It's the same concept. Obtain the frame of the shape layer, check if the touch is inside the frame, then allow (or disallow) the gesture recognizer to begin.

Comment: Can you provide any additional info? What doesn't work? The delegate method is not being called? The gesture recognizer action is not being called? You're returning false from the delegate, but the action is still being called?

Comment: I get the error in the delegate line: Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?'

Comment: Take a look at my class declaration at the top. I'm declaring that my class conforms to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Do the same with your ViewController.

Comment: Now it works! BUT.. Its working only when I click near the circlePath2 bounds and not on the circlePath2 exactly, why?

Comment: Please share the code inside your `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` function

Comment: `let location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(view);

                                                                                                                 return CGRectContainsPoint(circlePath2.bounds, location)`
I think it's because the position of the circlePath2 is not exactly where I code it to be

Comment: This can be a difficult concept to wrap your head around, but `location` and `circlePath2.bounds` refer to different coordinate spaces. You'll want to make sure that the arguments you pass to `CGRectContainsPoint` are in the same coordinate space. In your case, if `view` refers to the view who's layer `circlePath2` has been added to, then you want to use `circlePath2.frame`. A layer's `frame` is represented in the coordinate space of its superlayer, whereas `bounds` is the layer itself.